# AWS Glue Notebook update job timeout

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue

I have a AWS glue notebook that should run for about 15 minutes. The current job timeout value in job details is set to 10 minutes. I'm not able to directly change this value through the UI since it's a glue notebook. Instead, it says I should use %magic commands, but I don't see a magic command for job timeout, only idle_timeout. How can I update the job timeout value so my job can run for longer than 10 minutes?